# Get all SSH host keys before connecting with paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

How can I efficiently get all SSH server host keys using paramiko?

My attempt so far is the following. First get all the key types (returns a tuple of strings):

```py
ssh_transport = paramiko.transport.Transport('%s:%s' % (ip_address, 22))
ssh_transport.start_client()
options = ssh_transport.get_security_options()
ssh_transport.close()
```

for the above, this is a shorter method:

```
client_key_types = paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_keys
```

Next, loop through the key types, get the option object, assign the target key type, start the client, and get the host key:

```py
for key_type in options.key_types:
    ssh_transport = paramiko.transport.Transport('%s:%s' % (ip_address, 22))
    inner_options = ssh_transport.get_security_options()
    inner_options.key_types = (key_type,)

    ssh_transport.start_client()
    key = ssh_transport.get_remote_server_key()
    ssh_transport.close()
```

In the above code, you'll get an exception if you try with an unsupported key type.

The code works, but it seems horribly inefficient to do it this way.

Is there a better way of doing this using something built into Paramiko? In the end, I'm only trying to verify the identity of the server on my first connection, with minimal infrastructure needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the [answer is no](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/626).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Well, it is possibly misdirected, but I was looking to store the key (or fingerprint I suppose) for all algorithms supported on the server. That way I could ID the server prior to using any other supported key I had. In the end, I suppose I'm looking to exert control over the negotiation, but perhaps that isn't the right thing to do. This all comes back to another question I had concerning the overall process of automating the verification of a server key.

Comment: And I'm not saying it is write, but the Bitvise SSH client for Windows seems to get several server keys, but maybe that is only after finalizing the connection? I'm open to any learning opportunities.

Comment: There's always only one host key type involved in the connection. It looks like you have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).

Comment: Yup, as I'm relatively new that's probably about right. As far as additional information to determine the real problem, I'll add a bit to the question. Thanks for your replies so far.

Comment: Sorry, but you addition still does not explain why you want to retrieve all host keys.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I need to learn a bit more about SSH connections before I go much further.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get list of host key types supported by Paramiko without opening a connection, you can read `Transport._preferred_keys`:

   ```
   print(paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_keys)
   ```
2. To get list of host key types supported by the server, you would have to parse Paramiko log file:

   ```
   DEB [20190407-07:20:15.255] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:[...] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:[...] server encrypt:[...] client mac:[...] server mac:[...] client compress:[...] server compress:[...] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
   ```

Comment: Is the  `_preferred_keys` property in order of what Paramiko thinks is right, or is this commonly understood to be the right order? Should I use a `ssh-ed25519` key instead of `ssh-rsa` since I control both client and server?

Comment: *"what Paramiko thinks is right, or is this commonly understood to be the right  order?"* -- That's about the same, isn't it?

Comment: I'm new to Paramiko, and to an extent, public key authentication.